# Django DRF: How to join tables and call a function?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a basic CRUD app made using Django Rest Framework where the app takes in a Delivery number from the user and lets them enter any issue with the Delivery for which the `DeliveryIssue` model is used in a simple modal form.

I want to add a way where once the Delivery number has been entered on the form, it can lookup the `Customer Name` and `Delivery Date` present in the `DeliveryInfo` model and show it on the form itself before submission. And then that information is saved alongwith the `DeliveryIssue` model.

```
class DeliveryIssue(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'APP_Delivery_Issue'

  delivery = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column = 'Delivery')
  issue_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column = 'Issue Category')
  issue = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column = 'Issue')
  detail = models.TextField(db_column = 'Detail')
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_column = 'Create Datetime')
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_column = 'Update Datetime')

class DeliveryInfo(models.Model):
  detail = models.CharField(db_column='Delivery', max_length=50, blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
  customer = models.CharField(db_column='Customer', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
  delivery_date = models.DateField(db_column='Delivery Date', blank=True, null=True)

  class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'INFO_DELIVERY'
```

I have read about [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save), but unsure how to use this in here. Here is the `serializers.py` file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import DeliveryIssue

class DeliveryIssueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = DeliveryIssue
    fields = '__all__'
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the delivery number stored? Why is there no relationship between the DeliveryInfo and the DeliveryIssue models? Is it prudent to show the name and date associated with an order to anyone who enters a delivery number (which is presumably sequential, not random, and therefore easy to guess)?

Comment: Hey Endre,

The delivery number is stored in the database as a separate table from where we will be looking up the values. I am not sure how relationships will work with `signals` in this case. The delivery number is just a way for the user to confirm that the delivery exists in the database and they are not entering the wrong number, and it will be in a non-editable input. I have added an example to my original question.

I am unable to find clear examples of django signals out here to support this case, so just want to confirm if that is the right way to go.